# XML format for Jenkins

Tags: python, xml, junit, xsd, jenkins

I am writing an automated test script in python and I need to integrate this to jenkins so that the test result output can be seen in jenkins for each module.

I am not so familiar with XML and I see that Jenkins is not able to understand the XML output I try to create in my script.

Is there any means in python by which I transform my XML format to the XSD provided by Jenkins?

> > Because of the restrictions I cannot install any libraries like lxml. I am having to use basic python libraries that comes with 2.7.1 version.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have a look at [generateDS](http://www.rexx.com/~dkuhlman/generateDS.html)